# MS SQL writes SQL select statement using intersects. Trying to optimise the query using any other method

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL writes SQL select statement using intersects. Can someone help me to optimise the following query using sub query or some other method?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST('EDIT' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'test',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{8DBF084C-E575-4739-B37A-F732F72CFF69}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'City',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{32ED6082-1145-4331-9D29-F47E19090A0A}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Sectors' 
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{000C7660-E35B-4734-B1DA-A42A79A7B827}') 
    mytable 
WHERE [City] like 'l%' 
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ID, 
        CAST('EDIT' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'test',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{8DBF084C-E575-4739-B37A-F732F72CFF69}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'City',
        CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{32ED6082-1145-4331-9D29-F47E19090A0A}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Sectors' 
    FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{000C7660-E35B-4734-B1DA-A42A79A7B827}') 
    mytable 
WHERE 
[Sectors] LIKE '%{844C2884-4E6A-4F38-9DE4-7CCF7DDF06C6}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{E038C7E9-5570-490C-8E27-096DC745DCD1}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{C6A54BF5-B5D0-4D54-8465-6122CA9D0629}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{B4922161-F28D-4EC2-8F32-D8F5EEF9A472}%';
```

Comment: 1) Why you are casting all the retuned data as NVARCHAR(MAX) ??  2) Can you replace these scalar UDFs with joins ??

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL is writing queries? Not humans or at least something like hibernate?

Try somehing like it (no tested)

```
SELECT ID, 
    CAST('EDIT' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'test',
    CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{8DBF084C-E575-4739-B37A-F732F72CFF69}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'City',
    CAST([dbo].[SC_GetVersionedFieldValue](ID, '{32ED6082-1145-4331-9D29-F47E19090A0A}') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Sectors' 
FROM [dbo].[Items] WHERE [TemplateID] = '{000C7660-E35B-4734-B1DA-A42A79A7B827}'

AND [City] like 'l%' 

AND

[Sectors] LIKE '%{844C2884-4E6A-4F38-9DE4-7CCF7DDF06C6}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{E038C7E9-5570-490C-8E27-096DC745DCD1}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{C6A54BF5-B5D0-4D54-8465-6122CA9D0629}%'
OR [Sectors] LIKE '%{B4922161-F28D-4EC2-8F32-D8F5EEF9A472}%'
```